# Spring Scheduling Quartz and thousands of jobs

Tags: spring, mongodb, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

According to the business logic of my Spring Boot application with Quartz Scheduling and MongoDB as Job persistent storage, every user of the system can create the postponed job that must be executed at some point in time. The user chooses the time when it must be executed.

Right now I'm thinking about the approach where every user will create a dedicated `JobDetail` for every postponed job, something like this:

```
schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler().addJob(jobDetail(), true, true);
```

The issue I can potentially see here, that with this approach I can quickly create thousands of jobs in Quartz scheduler. Previously I never scheduled such amount of jobs in Spring Scheduling with Quartz and don't know how the system will handle it. Is it a good idea to implement the system in such way and will Spring Scheduling Quartz handle such amount of jobs without problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Quartz itself can handle thousands of jobs and triggers without any issues.

If you are going to have many jobs executing concurrently, just make sure that you configure Quartz with a sufficient number of worker threads. The number of worker threads should be typically equal to the maximum number of jobs that can be running concurrently + some small buffer (10% or so) just in case.

From what you write I assume that your jobs will be one-off jobs, i.e. each job will be executed only once. If that is the case, Quartz can automatically discard your jobs as soon as they finish executing unless your jobs are marked as durable. Quartz automatically removes non-durable jobs if they are not scheduled to run in the future. This feature may help you reduce the total number of registered jobs.

I hope this helps. If not, please ask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'm going to have both at the same time - one-off jobs and jobs with the CronTrigger and CronExpression. Could you please tell me what exact property should I use in order to configure the number of worker threads ? Is it something like 
 `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount` ? Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, you nailed it. See http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigThreadPool.html.